# PostgreSQL: select xml field by date range

Tags: postgresql, xpath

I have an XML field named "driver_license" with the following content:

```
<driver_license>
 <no>123</no>
 <issue_date>2023-11-20</issue_date>
</driver_license>
```

I need to select records with issue_date greater than a certain date.

On MSSQL I can do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM persons AS t
WHERE t.driver_license.exist( 'driver_license/issue_date[.>=''2023-12-04'']' ) = 1
```

But I have no idea how to do this on PostgreSQL.
This is not working:

```
WHERE xmlexists('//driver_license/issue_date[.>=''2023-12-04'']' PASSING BY REF t.driver_license )
```

Because >= works only with integers.

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `XMLTABLE` to produce a table based on an XML value :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE ('//driver_license'
                     PASSING t.driver_license
                     COLUMNS issue_date date PATH 'issue_date'
                    ) x
WHERE x.issue_date > '2023-10-04';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/KCiibBn2)